# OpenCv findcontours() too much contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have shape that I want to extract contours from ( I need to have number of contours right -two), but in hierarchy I get 4 or more instead of two contours. I just cant realise why ,it is obvious and there is no noise, I used diletation and erosion before.

[image: before findcontours()]

[image: after findcontours()]

I tried to change all parametars, and nothing. Also I tried with image of white square and didnt work. There is my line for that:

```
Mat I = imread("test.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
I.convertTo(B, CV_8U);    
findContours(B, contour_vec, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Why is contour so disconnected?What to do to have 2 contours in hierarchy?

Comment: I count  5 contours (2 external and 2 internal, and one at top right). The second image is just garbage produced by `findContours`. Use `findContours(B.clone(), ...)` to avoid to corrupt `B`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your image there are 5 contours: 2 external contours, 2 internal contours and 1 on the top right.

You can discard internal and external contours looking if they are oriented CW or CCW. You can do this with [contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) with oriented flag:

> **oriented** – Oriented area flag. If it is true, the function returns a signed area value, depending on the contour orientation (clockwise or counter-clockwise). Using this feature you can determine orientation of a contour by taking the sign of an area. By default, the parameter is false, which means that the absolute value is returned.

So, drawing external contours in *red*, and internal in *green*, you get:

[image]

You can then store only external contours (see `externalContours`) in the code below:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load grayscale image
    Mat1b B = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Find contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(B.clone(), contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Create output image
    Mat3b out;
    cvtColor(B, out, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<vector<Point>> externalContours;
    for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Find orientation: CW or CCW
        double area = contourArea(contours[i], true);

        if (area >= 0) 
        {
            // Internal contours
            drawContours(out, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            // External contours
            drawContours(out, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

            // Save external contours
            externalContours.push_back(contours[i]);
        }
    }

    imshow("Out", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Please remember that `findContours` corrupts input image (the second image you're showing is *garbage*). Just pass a clone of the image to `findContours` to avoid corruptions of the original image.